# Why does Matlab find '.' and '..' dirs when reading folder content using dir('')?

Tags: matlab, directory

I read the contaent of a folder using x = dir(folder_name) in Matlab.
Why does the first two rows of the field `name` of the created structure `x` are `'.'` and `'..'` folders?

Comment: thx. should I delete the question?

Comment: That's not needed. It will be closed automatically but stays so people with a search that is like yours will come across this question and see the original automatically!